# Create json object of undefined content

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am working with an exiting API that expects a "Metadata" field as part of its json payload. That "Metadata" field is a json object that is completely free-form. Currently, I need to read this data provided from another source, do some enrichment, then pass it on. I am struggling with how to define this "Metadata" object so that it can be any valid json object. OR, if that field was not provided, an empty json object.

I attempted to use org.json.JSONObject like so.

```
//meta is the json string read from the db
JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(meta);
message.Metadata = jsonobject;
```

However, jackson, not unexpectedly, threw a serialization error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered...
```

This is a critical requirement that I'm guessing I am missing some relatively obvious solution to. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATED FIX**

As suggested by @shmosel I just switched the json object to a com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode and all works beautifully.

// working code (rough of course)
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

```
JsonNode rootNode = null;
try {
       rootNode = mapper.readTree(meta);
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }

message.Metadata = rootNode;
```

Comment: Why don't you use a [`JsonNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) tree?

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I didn't think of that. If you would like to add an answer I will mark it as accepted ASAP.